# API for a real life like 3D avatar that could read given text. Ulta HAL for Mac/Linux?

Tags: api, 3d, text-to-speech, avatar

I am looking to build a voice based interactive automation system. To make the experience more realistic I am looking for 3D avatars that could read a given text(response) in real time.

The closest I found something on the net is Ultra HAL for windows (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEtgfXbpCqI). I need something similar, expressive, programmable through an API and preferable for a MAC or Linux. TTS is not that mandatory.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://www.livingactor.com is very cartoonish and only for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there is nothing comparable to the (15 year old) [Haptek](http://www.haptek.com/) avatar technology (the underlying tech Ultra HAL uses). Even on the Windows platform. We use Haptek for [Cassandra](http://www.ejtalk.com/v2/cass/cassChron.html) for all the reasons you want such a package. To my knowledge nothing else supports such high quality, 3D, emotively & verbally autonomous characters. Note: In-game 3D avatars are all carefully **scripted and acted** scenes and not actually **interactive**.

I would like to extend the question/request to the Android platform. Many developers could make great use of that. Cassandra certainly would.